# How to add hyperlinks to list of IP's in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openoffice.org, vba

Excel 2003 spreadsheet, column 'A' contain list of IP adresses, one per cell (without http://). How to add hyperlinks to these IPs? (using OpenOffice)

Comment: Please supply a sample of the input.  Do you mean like   64.4.11.42

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

64.4.11.42

in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

`=HYPERLINK("http://" & A1,A1)`   and copy down.

**EDIT#1**:

To convert the IP's in place, select the cells and run this small macro:

```
Sub HyperMaker()
    Dim r As Range
    Dq = Chr(34)
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & Dq & "http://" & r.Text & Dq & ";" & Dq & r.Text & Dq & ")"
    Next r
End Sub
```

This, of course assumes that the formula separator is the **;** rather than the **,**

Comment: yes, input is like in the example above. But formula gives `Err:508`, because it uses the comma separator. Semicolon should be used instead of comma: `=HYPERLINK("http://" & A1;A1)`, then it works. It gives an extra column with the same data, though. Is it possible to get without extra column?

Comment: There is some bug in OpenOffice, when I trying to use any of the macro, OpenOffice Calc produces a runtime
error (`BASIC runtime error, Object variable not set`).

Comment: Try replacing **Selection** with a specific range.

Comment: ok, I have tried this:

`Sub HyperMaker()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1:A90")
    Dq = Chr(34)
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & Dq & "http://" & r.Text & Dq & ";" & Dq & r.Text & Dq & ")"
    Next r
End Sub`
 
When trying run macro from Macro Selector window, it gives another error: `"BASIC syntax error. Unknown data type range."`
I think OpenOffice API is different, and no "Range" is used in OpenOffice anymore.

Comment: Sub HyperMaker()
    Dim r As Range
    Dq = Chr(34)
    For Each r In Range("A1:A100")
        r.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & Dq & "http://" & r.Text & Dq & ";" & Dq & r.Text & Dq & ")"
    Next r
End Sub

Comment: Same error, `"BASIC syntax error. Unknown data type range."`